# Include rosserial_arduino_demos/Adc.h

Tags: ros, arduino, include, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm using ros-electric and try to compile rosserial_arduino_demos/sketches/ADC...
Problem: missing header file

rosserial_arduino_demos/Adc.h

Where can I find this include file ?

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11454/include-rosserial_arduino_demos/adc.h/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Our docs are ahead of our release in debs (this will be fixed very shortly). In 0.1.0, this message was in the rosserial_arduino_demo package.

You can certainly do a:

```
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_library.py <sketchbook> rosserial_arduino_demo
```

But I would really recommend you upgrade to the latest (soon to be 0.2.0) code by doing a source checkout:

```
cd <some directory on your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH>
hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg
rosmake rosserial
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You find the very interesting but outdated tutorial for this demo at:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20Oscilloscope

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1